# What is the proper way for indicating lives being saved?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Would an apostrophe for possession be appropriate?

For instance would the following be proper use:

> "which directly contributed to less suffering and lives’ saved"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think any apostrophe is necessary. 'Saved' is acting as an adjective, qualifying the plural word 'lives'. Latin would parse 'lives' as the dative case of the noun, not the genetive (possessive).